# Cakephp 2.3.1 HABTM Edit Form Displaying Drop Down Box Instead of Multi Select Box

Tags: forms, cakephp, edit, has-and-belongs-to-many, multi-select

I have a HABTM relationship between Dancers and Dances.  Things seem to be working as expected except that on edit.ctp for editing my Dances, CakePHP is showing a drop down box instead of a the multi-select box I was expecting.  What's crazy to me is that the multi-select box is working the other way with edit.ctp for editing Dancers!  I can't figure out why it would work one way but not the other.

Here is my Dance Model defining the relationship between the Dance and the Dancer:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Dancer' => array(
            'className' => 'Dancer',
            'joinTable' => 'dancers_dances',
            'foreignKey' => 'dance_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'dancer_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        )
    );
```

This is my Dance Controller:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Dance->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid dance'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Dance->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The dance has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The dance could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Dance.' . $this->Dance->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Dance->find('first', $options);
    }
    $users = $this->Dance->User->find('list');
    $dancers = $this->Dance->Dancer->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'dancers'));
}
```

This is my edit.ctp for the Dance View

```
<div class="dances form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Dance'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Dance'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('dance_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('users_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('Dancers');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $this->Form->value('Dance.id')), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $this->Form->value('Dance.id'))); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Dances'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Dancers'), array('controller' => 'dancers', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Dancers'), array('controller' => 'dancers', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think the relevant tables would be:
dancers,
dancers_dances,
dances

On the dancers_dances table I have the following columns:
id,
dancer_id,
dance_id

Let me know if more info would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sad part is I couldn't see anything wrong there :(. Try setting debug level higher than 0, also make sure if edit.ctp is indeed in the path it is supposed to be. I once wasted hours editing file with a same name on a different location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can get rid of most settings inside your HABTM definition because you're using Cake Conventions already;

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Dancer' => array(
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

But the problem is in the name of your input inside the form, which should be **singular** and named after the model which it's related to;

```
echo $this->Form->input('Dancer');
```

You can see some examples in the manual here (look for the 'Tag' example in this section):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

Comment: Perfect.  You're right the name of the input inside the form had to be singular, the same as my Dancer model.  I learned something new today.

Comment: Glad I could help. Problems like this can be confusing and are easily overlooked, even by experienced CakePHP developers. Good luck with your project and enjoy CakePHP